# optimization doesn't respect constraint

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, scipy, linear-programming, minimization

I have an optimization problem and I'm solving it with scipy and the minimization module. I uses SLSQP as method, because it is the only one, which fits to my problem. The function to optimize is  a cost function with 'x' as a list of percentages. I have some constraints which has to be respected:

- At first, the sum of the percentages should be 1 (PercentSum(x)) This constrain is added as 'eg' (equal) as you can see in the code.
- The second constraint is about a physical value which must be less then 'proberty1Max '. This constrain is added as 'ineq' (inequal). So if 'proberty1 < proberty1Max ' the function should  be bigger than 0. Otherwise the function should be 0. The functions is differentiable.

Below you can see a model of my try. The problem is the 'constrain' function. I get solutions, where the sum of 'prop' is bigger than 'probertyMax'.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

class objects:
     def __init__(self, percentOfInput, min, max, cost, proberty1, proberty2):
         self.percentOfInput = percentOfInput
         self.min = min
         self.max = max
         self.cost = cost
         self.proberty1 = proberty1
         self.proberty2 = proberty2

class data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.objectList = list()
        self.objectList.append(objects(10, 0, 20, 200, 2, 7))
        self.objectList.append(objects(20, 5, 30, 230, 4, 2))
        self.objectList.append(objects(30, 10, 40, 270, 5, 9))
        self.objectList.append(objects(15, 0, 30, 120, 2, 2))
        self.objectList.append(objects(25, 10, 40, 160, 3, 5))
        self.proberty1Max = 1
        self.proberty2Max = 6

D = data()

def optiFunction(x):
    for index, obj in enumerate(D.objectList):
        obj.percentOfInput = x[1]

    costSum = 0
    for obj in D.objectList:
        costSum += obj.cost * obj.percentOfInput

    return costSum

def PercentSum(x):
    y = np.sum(x) -100
    return y

def constraint(x, val):
    for index, obj in enumerate(D.objectList):
        obj.percentOfInput = x[1]
    prop = 0
    if val == 1:
        for obj in D.objectList:
            prop += obj.proberty1 * obj.percentOfInput

        return D.proberty1Max -prop
    else: 
        for obj in D.objectList:
            prop += obj.proberty2 * obj.percentOfInput

        return D.proberty2Max -prop

def checkConstrainOK(cons, x):
    for con in cons:
        y = con['fun'](x)
        if con['type'] == 'eq' and y != 0:
            print("eq constrain not respected y= ", y)
            return False
        elif con['type'] == 'ineq' and y <0:
            print("ineq constrain not respected y= ", y)
            return False
    return True

initialGuess = []
b = []
for obj in D.objectList:
     initialGuess.append(obj.percentOfInput)
     b.append((obj.min, obj.max))
     bnds = tuple(b)

cons = list()
cons.append({'type': 'eq', 'fun': PercentSum})
cons.append({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x, val=1 :constraint(x, val) })
cons.append({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x, val=2 :constraint(x, val) })

solution = minimize(optiFunction,initialGuess,method='SLSQP',\
                            bounds=bnds,constraints=cons,options={'eps':0.001,'disp':True})
print('status ' + str(solution.status))
print('message ' + str(solution.message))
checkConstrainOK(cons, solution.x)
```

There is no way to find a solution, but the output is this:

```
Positive directional derivative for linesearch    (Exit mode 8)
        Current function value: 4900.000012746761
        Iterations: 7
        Function evaluations: 21
        Gradient evaluations: 3
status 8
message Positive directional derivative for linesearch
```

Where is my fault? In this case it ends with mode 8, because the example is very small. With bigger data the algorithm ends with mode 0. But I think it should ends with a hint that an constraint couldn't be hold.

It doesn't make a difference, if proberty1Max is set to 4 or to 1. But in the case it is 1, there could not be a valid solution.

PS: I changed a lot in this question... Now the code is executable.

EDIT: 
1.Okay, I learned, an inequal constrain is accepted if the output is positiv (>0). In the past I think <0 would also be accepted. Because of this the constrain function is now a little bit shorter.

2. What about the constrain. In my real solution I add some constrains using a loop. In this case it is nice to feed a function with an index of the loop and in the function this index is used to choose an element of an array. In my example here, the "val" decides if the constrain is for proberty1 oder property2. What the constrain mean is, how much of a property is in the hole mix. So I'm calculating the property multiplied with the percentOfInput. "prop" is the sum of this over all objects.

I think there might be a connection to the issue tux007 mentioned in the comments. [link to the issue](https://github.com/stevengj/nlopt/issues/254)
I think the optimizer doesn't work correct, if the initial guess is not a valid solution. 
Linear programming is not good for overdetermined equations. My problem doesn't have a unique solution, its an approximation.

Comment: SLSQP expects continuous and differentiable (smooth) functions. I think you are violating that, which may lead to problems. (Although you say `max` and `tat` are constant data, which is strange).

Comment: Hey Erwin, I just updated the question. I hope it's enough information.

Comment: `conMax = [{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': MaxLimit(x)}]` you are not passing the callable `MaxLimit` as a constraint, but the constant value returned by `MaxLimit(x)`. Is that on purpose?

Comment: hey dion, good point! I updated the code. It's a summary... In the real code I'm using a lamda function, because MaxLimit() has more then one parameter and I add some constrain with an loop.

Comment: maybe it is connected with this bug https://github.com/stevengj/nlopt/issues/254

Comment: It might be helpful if you post either an algebraic or pseudo-algebraic representation of your optimization problem. To me, it seems you are trying to maximize `sum_i cost[i] * percentOfInput[i]`, subject to `sum_i percentOfInput[i] == 1` and ... something else? Can you confirm or correct what I wrote, and fill in the "something else"? I have a feeling that your problem can be formulated as a linear program, which you could solve using an LP solver instead of something like SLSQP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment I think this is the problem:
[Misleading output from....](https://github.com/stevengj/nlopt/issues/254)

If you have a look at the latest changes, the constrain is not satisfied, but the algorithm says: "Positive directional derivative for linesearch"